# Numpad behavior incorrect with vim.exe - Windows

Tags: terminal, microsoft-windows

On Windows with an installation of gvim 8.1, Numpad behavior is different between the GUI and the console.

The GUI (`gvim.exe`) has a `TERM` of `builtin_gui` and the keypad (with Numlock On) works properly.  By properly, I mean in insert mode, when you hit <kbd>Num 0</kbd>, it inserts a `0`.

However, the console version (`vim.exe`) has a `TERM` of `win32` and the keypad (with Numlock On) inserts extended characters such as:

0. ╬┌
1. ╬▐
2. ╬Γ
3. ╬µ
4. ╬Ω
5. ╬ε
6. ╬≥
7. ╬÷
8. ╬ ·
9. ╬■

How would I go about changing the behavior of the numpad in the console?  I have tried looking at the default vimscripts such as `mswin.vim` to see if there is any obvious behavior that could affect the function of the numpad, but I didn't see anything.  I also searched Google and vi SE, but all answers I seemed to find had to do with the various terminal programs that people were using.  This issue is when using `vim.exe` within the native Windows command prompt.

---

**Edit:** Providing Version information below.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled May 18 2018 18:26:56)
MS-Windows 32-bit console version
Included patches: 1
Compiled by mool@tororo
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +eval              -mouseshape        -tag_any_white
+arabic            +ex_extra          +multi_byte        -tcl
+autocmd           +extra_search      +multi_lang        +termguicolors
+autoservername    +farsi             -mzscheme          +terminal
-balloon_eval      +file_in_path      -netbeans_intg     -tgetent
+balloon_eval_term +find_in_path      +num64             -termresponse
-browse            +float             +packages          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    +folding           +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       -footer            -perl              +title
+channel           +gettext/dyn       +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           -hangul_input      -postscript        +user_commands
+clientserver      +iconv/dyn         +printer           +vertsplit
+clipboard         +insert_expand     +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_compl     +job               -python            +visual
+cmdline_hist      +jumplist          -python3           +visualextra
+cmdline_info      +keymap            +quickfix          +viminfo
+comments          +lambda            +reltime           +vreplace
+conceal           +langmap           +rightleft         +vtp
+cryptv            +libcall           -ruby              +wildignore
+cscope            +linebreak         +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorbind        +lispindent        +signs             +windows
+cursorshape       +listcmds          +smartindent       +writebackup
+dialog_con        +localmap          +startuptime       -xfontset
+diff              -lua               +statusline        -xim
+digraphs          +menu              -sun_workshop      -xpm_w32
-dnd               +mksession         +syntax            -xterm_save
-ebcdic            +modify_fname      +tag_binary
+emacs_tags        +mouse             +tag_old_static
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME\defaults.vim"
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32  -DFEAT_CSCOPE -DFEAT_TERMINAL  -DFEAT_JOB_CHANNEL      -DWINVER=0x0501 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 /MP -DHAVE_STDINT_H /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG /arch:IA32 /Zl /MT -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_HUGE /Fd.\ObjCi386/ /Zi
Linking: link  /nologo /subsystem:console,5.01 /opt:ref /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib /machine:i386   libcmt.lib  user32.lib          WSock32.lib  /PDB:vim.pdb -debug
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Can you try it with `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: I see the same non-functional keypad with my default Vim 8.1.374. This might depend on the codepage and your encoding option, but for me with a default codepage of 850 and latin1 encoding it doesn't work (the same for unicode codepage and utf-8 encoding). I just tried the latest available version 8.1.2256 and it works correctly there. Could be patch 8.1.457

Comment: @MaximKim same thing when executing `vim -u NONE`.

Comment: @DamianT. Please update your Vim version

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I am attempting to find a newer installer and also get a compiler installed so I can try to compile from source.

Comment: @DamianT. Here we go: https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer

Comment: Thanks, @ChristianBrabandt.  I was able to install the latest nightly build and it indeed fixed the problem.  If you want, post an answer explaining that it was a bug and I will accept as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the original 8.1 version, that has since been fixed (possibly by patch [v8.1.0457](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0457)).

You can always test the latest nightly builds from the [vim/vim-win32-installer](https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases) repository. That one will provide nightly builds (and if I have the time, I'll also have the installer and the binaries signed using [signpath.io](https://app.signpath.io))